# How to read text-file in php and send the results to other html file

Tags: php, html

I want to use php to read text file from server and send the lines read to another html.

for example:
read data.txt from a.php and send the lines read to a_body.html, and at the end of a.php call the a_body.html to show the results.
The lines to read in data.txt is about 50 lines in average.

Please, could provide some examples? i am new using php.
thanks

Comment: did u tried anything?

Comment: you can grab text into a string with file_get_contents

Comment: you can call with ajax a.php and print results with javascript

Comment: Please could provide a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the data file and the created one is on the same server, this should work

```
<?php

    $data_read = file_get_contents("data.txt");

    // do stuff

    $success = (file_put_contents("a_body.html",$data_read)?true:false);

?>
```

instead of `file_get_contents()` u also can use the `file()` function to get the data.txt line by line as an array. Or use `fopen() - fread() - fclose()` if needed.